# Updating data with Adapter.Update() in service based DB, program tries to override Identity

Tags: c#, .net, database

I have to write an Address Book in C# using service based DataBase and encountered weird problem. When I call `personTableAdapter.Update(LastDataRow)` it tries to override identity in my database and throws an exception.

Is there any good way to prevent this? Perhaps force the program to ignore that field?

[Here is the whole program](https://github.com/Hajtosek/CSharp/blob/master/ServiceBased%20AddressBook/AddressBookV2/Form1.cs):

```
private DataRow LastDataRow = null;

    private void UpdateRowToDatabase()
    {
        if (LastDataRow != null)
        {
            if (LastDataRow.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            {
                personTableAdapter.Update(LastDataRow);
            }
        }
    }

    private void regionBindingSource_PositionChanged(
      object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BindingSource thisBindingSource =
          (BindingSource)sender;
        DataRow ThisDataRow =
          ((DataRowView)thisBindingSource.Current).Row;
        if (ThisDataRow == LastDataRow)
        {
            throw new ApplicationException("It seems the" +
              " PositionChanged event was fired twice for" +
              " the same row");
        }

        UpdateRowToDatabase();

        LastDataRow = ThisDataRow;
    }

    private void MainForm_FormClosed(
      object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateRowToDatabase();
    }
```

Full Exception text:https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwFCu.jpg

Comment: Can you show the `personTableAdapter` update query ?

Comment: I haven't constructed any... I'm using autogenerated thing. It's available on github. (https://github.com/Hajtosek/CSharp/blob/master/ServiceBased%20AddressBook/AddressBookV2/DataSet1.Designer.cs) It's pretty complex thing.

Comment: Please, add full text of exception

Comment: http://imgur.com/buwWo7m - Exception

Comment: The trouble is in DataSet generated update query `this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE [dbo].[Person] SET [Id] = @Id` , I can't precisely tell solution in your business rules and approach of id generation. You can `SET IDENTITY_INSERT person ON;` for example or play with Person.Id column properties in DataSet for eleminate `SET ID=@id` in update. May be this thougths help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Moved from comment*
The trouble is in DataSet generated update query `this._adapter.UpdateCommand.CommandText = @"UPDATE [dbo].[Person] SET [Id] = @Id` , I can't precisely tell solution in your business rules and approach of id generation. You can `SET IDENTITY_INSERT person ON;` for example or play with Person.Id column properties in DataSet for eleminate `SET ID=@id` in update. May be this thougths help you